# subsetting a data.frame using a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a data.frame, and I want to subset it every 10 rows and then applied a function to the subset, save the object, and remove the previous object. Here is what I got so far

```
L3 <- LETTERS[1:20]
df <- data.frame(1:391, "col", sample(L3, 391, replace = TRUE))
names(df) <- c("a", "b", "c")

b <- seq(from=1, to=391, by=10)
nsamp <- 0
for(i in seq_along(b)){
a <- i+1
nsamp <- nsamp+1
df_10 <- df[b[nsamp]:b[a], ]
res <- lapply(seq_along(df_10$b), function(x){...}
saveRDS(res, file="res.rds")
rm(res)
}
```

My problem is the `for loop` crashes when reaching the last element of my sequence `b`

Comment: why are you saving inside the for loop? You seem to be saving over the same file again and again because you don't change the name of the file. Close the Lapply function.

Comment: the function reads some files that are really big, this is why I want to subset in bunch of 10 and then save and remove them to save RAM

Comment: Are the objects so big they won't all fit in memory? Much better ways to do this would be to use lists (e.g., `my_subsets = split(df, 1:nrow(df) %/% 10)` and then `lapply` or `for` loop over the subsets) or better, use `data.table` or `dplyr` with their "doing things by group" abilities.

Comment: the function use the information on the `data.frame` `s2c_10` to apply a function from 'sleuth` package that reads `hdf5` files that are so big, so this is the reason I want to apply the function to chunks. Thanks @Gregor for the use of split

Comment: @Gregor, if you elaborate a answer with the use of `split` I will give accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When partitioning data, `split` is your friend. It will create a list with each data subset as an item which is then easy to iterate over.

```
dfs = split(df, 1:nrow(df) %/% 10)
```

Then your for loop can be simplified to something like this (untested... I'm not exactly sure what you're doing because example data seems to switch from `df` to `sc2_10` and I only hope your column named `b` is different from your vector named `b`):

```
for(i in seq_along(dfs)){
  res <- lapply(seq_along(dfs[[i]]$b), function(x){...}
  saveRDS(res, file = sprintf("res_%s.rds", i))
  rm(res)
}
```

I also modified your save file name so that you aren't overwriting the same file every time.